# Extracting a certain value and displaying it on a different page on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have recently been using Sharepoint Online. One of my tasks involves displaying the *number of entries* in a SharePoint list on the **Home page** of the site and when **clicked upon** must lead to the list page.

So far, I have figured out how I can add a link on the "#Number of Entries". Pl refer to the image. I need help in displaying the **Actual Number of Entries**.

Any help would be appreciated. Image of sample web layout (for Representational Purposes only)

[image]

Comment: For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the SharePoint Stack Exchange (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site. Use this tag only for programming questions which may involve SharePoint.

Comment: @Shakespear Duly noted. I have posted the same question on the link you provided. Thanks.